# How to excite a fluorescent lamp without connecting it?

Tags: discharge, electrical, lamp, field

I'm a newbie in electrical engineering, so this might be a silly question. But are there any standard ways to create an electric field over a volume of air, strong enough to excite a compact fluorescent lamp?

I've seen these videos where people use plasma globes to do this. The electrical field outside of the globe is strong enough to do this, so there must be some way of achieving this.

To give an idea of the shape of field I need, imagine a conveyor belt with fluorescent lamps on it, which pass by. I would need to aim an electric field as such that the fluorescent lamps light up as they pass by.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this for an art installation or an actual engineered system?

Comment: There seems to be videos on youtube that shows fluorescent light can glow in microwave oven

Comment: All you need is high V AC E field pallalel

Comment: [It seems to work with a HV power line](http://www.808.dk/pv.asp?p=Fluorescent_tubes_under_power_lines.jpg&g=photos-denmark).

Comment: Strong enough E-field. Some frequencies are better than others but sheer amplitude usually cuts it.

Comment: Sometimes a CFL in my table lamp is glowing when I touch it...

Comment: Tesla coil is a popular option.

Comment: High power radio transmitters. Flouro tubes are usually glowing in the boxes at old TV transmitter and AM transmitter sites. Probably easy to fudge with an antenna under the conveyor belt. I expect you to need a min of 25 - 50 watts. Wifi/cellphone/bluetooth is not going to do it.  Maybe talk to some local Ham radio chaps, they have these power levels, and easy to go wave a flouro around their antennas and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

A 2.545GHz Microwave beam run axially (along the length) of a straight fluorescent lamp has been proven to excite the plasma in the lamp and make it glow ([link](https://archive.org/stream/37MicrowaveExcitationOfFluorescentLamps/37+Microwave+Excitation+of+Fluorescent+Lamps_djvu.txt)). But containing that on something like a moving conveyor belt would be problematic for anyone working in the area. What is your purpose here? Are you wanting to test the lamps before packing them? Because if so, this would not tell you that the lamp as a whole is functioning, only that the gasses and phosphor coatings are present. The ballast / ignition system would not be tested by this, and those are the parts most likely to not be functioning.